# Было изучено или были изучены?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые

Скажите, пожалуйста, 500 дел БЫЛИ ИЗУЧЕНЫ в архивах или 500 дел БЫЛО ИЗУЧЕНО в архивах? И каким правилом это объяснить?

Answer (score 3):

В рассматриваемой конструкции сказуемое может иметь как форму единственного, так и форму множественного числа.

Выбираем форму ед. числа: 500 дел **было изучено** в архивах (указывается  совокупность предметов).

Розенталь §184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте) [XLIII. СОГЛАСОВАНИЕ СКАЗУЕМОГО С ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

Форма единственного числа сказуемого **указывает на совокупность предметов**, форма множественного числа – на отдельные предметы

Answer (score 3):

В этом случае норма вариативна. Выбор зависит от логических оттенков смысла.

Если хотите подчеркнуть, что дела изучались по отдельности, [дистрибутивно](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Distributive_plural) (англ.), то "были изучены".

Если хотите сказать, что дела мыслятся как некая общая совокупность (например, по признаку общего рассмотрения вопроса) - то "было изучено".