# Почему «тех, кто обожает» вм. «тех, кто обожают»

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число

> Любители вафель делятся на **тех**, кто **обожает** их мягкими и **тех**, кто **предпочитает** хрустящие.

Интересно, почему обязательно следует поставить «обожает» и «предпочитает» в единственное число, несмотря на присутствие множественного числа «[тех](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82#Russian)».

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443200/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc/443203#443203

Comment: Вопрос следовало бы переформулировать. Выражение "одно вместо другого" подразумевает, что первое правильней,  предпочтительней и т. п..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любители вафель делятся на тех, **кто обожает** их мягкими, и тех, **кто предпочитает** хрустящие.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_05)

При подлежащем – относительном местоимении кто (в функции союзного слова в придаточном предложении) сказуемое может стоять как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа, например:
а)      Все, кто не потерял еще головы, были против (Сергеев-Ценский); ...Те, кто не успел к двери, кинулись в радостной панике к окнам (Макаренко);

**Интересно разное решение в одном предложении:**

Все, **кто мог** ехать, **ехали** сами собой; **те, кто остановились**, решали сами с собой, что им надо было делать (Л. Толстой).

Возможность передвигаться была **индивидуальна для каждого,** а остановилась **целая группа**, поэтому согласование **разное** (в ед. и мн. числе).

Аналогично в приведенном примере речь идет **об индивидуальном предпочтении.**

Answer (score 0):

Потому что подлежащее в придаточных предложениях ("кто обожает их мягкими" и "кто предпочитает хрустящие") "кто", и сказуемые "обожает" и "предпочитает" согласуются с ним в единственном числе.

Comment: Я считаю интересным, как отличается от «*those who love(s)*» в английском языке.

Comment: Typically (not always), it works more like 'those, _each of whom_ loves'.

Comment: @Alex_ander Ah, that makes more sense. I recently posted one of my questions written only in Russian over there on another Russian SE site, and one member was thoughtful enough to correct an unnatural phrasing in my question. Could you edit my future questions accordingly whenever you spot any unnatural or ungrammatical phrasing? For future reference, I don't like the idea of leaving behind incomprehensible nonsense here.

Comment: OK, I'll try to do it whenever I find it necessary.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens  *Я считаю интересным, как отличается от «those who love(s)» в английском языке.* - Оh, well. Это действительно разные случаи. В русском языке "кто" не имеет множественного числа и используется как для множественного, так и для единственного, согласуясь при этом с формой единственного. These are really different cases. In Russian, "кто" does not have any plural form and is used for both the plural and the single ones, consistent with the singlar only. If it is necessary to emphasize the multiplicity of the subject, it's usually possible to replace "кто" with "которые".

Comment: @Alex_ander пожалуйста, используйте русский язык. We're on the Russian-language-only site, so let's speak Russian :)

Answer (score 0):

Пример вариативной нормы (ср. [с близким вопросом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431402/%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B/431405#431405)), характерной для безличных конструкций (выбор "нулевого субъекта" в единственном или множественном числе).

Субъект в единственном числе делает акцент на дистрибутивности, а во множественном - на парциальности.

В данном случае автор делает выбор в пользу [дистрибутивности](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Distributive_plural) (англ.).

В примере из Толстого возможно и написание "Все, кто ***могли*** ехать... ".